# what does a twitter /verify_credentials look like?

Tags: oauth, twitter

so, I just need to retrieve user basic info(/verify_credentials(twitter), /me(facebook) so Im trying to roll my own code for now

got it on facebook on second try since all I need is a request to graph.facebook.com/me + access_token

but now trying to do it with twitter has been incredibly painful, I just can't figure it out by the docs, so, please, what does a request to twitter api /verify_credentials look like?

what are the params?
twitter api, y u suck?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Facebook uses oAuth 2.0, which is much easier to implement than oAuth 1.0 (which twitter uses).

An example request to verify_credentials API could look like this:

`https://api.twitter.com/1/account/verify_credentials.json?oauth_consumer_key=XXX&oauth_nonce=XXX&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_token=XXX&oauth_timestamp=123456789&oauth_version=1.0&oauth_signature=YYY`

- oauth_consumer_key is self explanatory
- oauth_nonce can be pretty much a random string of characters
- oauth_signature_method is always HMAC-SHA1
- oauth_token is your access token
- oauth_timestamp is current UNIX timestamp (in UTC)
- oauth_version is always 1.0
- oauth_signature is your generated signature (which twitter will verify by reproducing)

You generate the value of the oauth_signature parameter by constructing a signature base string which consists of the following parts.

- HTTP method in upper case (in this case `GET`)
- an ampersand `&`
- URL-encoded base URI (everything from `https` up to and including verify_credentials.json)
- an ampersand `&`
- all request parameters in alphabetical order, url encoded. (oauth_signature should NOT be included in this though)

The pseudo code in the section [Signing requests in Twitters documentation](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/auth#signing-requests) describes the signing process elegantly:

```
httpMethod + "&" +
    url_encode(  base_uri ) + "&" +
    sorted_query_params.each  { | k, v |
        url_encode ( k ) + "%3D" +
        url_encode ( v )
    }.join("%26")
```

And then you sign the resulting base string using the consumer secret, and the access token secret. That's all there is too it :)

But before issuing any requests to the API you will of course need to actually get an access token. Once you grasp the oAuth 1.0 flow, and the signing process. You'll be home. Twitter's documentation does a great job at explaining the process, but it is a quite a bit to wrap your head around. Worth it though.